# Stringified Type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I feel like maybe I'm just not thinking this through clearly so forgive me if that's the case. Here's the problem:

I'm receiving exceptions formatted in a particular fashion. At the root of the error object I get your basic stuff: `message`, `status`, etc. However there's also a property call `error` which is a stringified object. When I create a type to model this error object, I'd like to not call that `error` property a 'string', that feels silly and not representative. However, that seems to be the only way I can define that property. (I realize it **is** a string, but that's the JSON equivalent to a type of `any`.)

My obvious expectation was that I could do something like `Stringified<ParsedErrorProperty>` (or something). That way when I receive that error object intellisense expects me to parse that property in order to access the attributes of that property, will know what attributes to expect post-parse,  and will pitch a fit if I fail to do so.

Comment: A `string` is a `string`, whether it's stringified JSON or not. If you have a predictable subset of strings you would like to check you can declare a type which is a union of strings. (eg. `type something = 'oneThing' | 'anotherThing'`)

Comment: You can look at some of the suggestions at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19244

Answer (score 2):

You can use an index signature to type a stringified object.

```js
type Stringified<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: string
};

interface Obj {
  value: number
}

const test : Stringified<Obj> = {
  value: "string"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My obvious expectation was that I could do something like Stringified (or something).

You'll need to create your own `Stringified` and `PrasedErrorProperty` along with `function parseError(error:string): Stringified<ParsedErrorProperty>`.

This is not provided natively.